# Execute Java program within Google App Engine using Python

Tags: java, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I have a blog site of sorts that is written in python using the google app engine.  Now, as an extension of my site I would like to add a feature to allow users to post/compile java code through my site. Thus, how could I go about getting my python site to compile and execute a java program that it receives through a textbox or textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the google app engine allows you to compile code dynamically (which I'm fairly certain it does not) or has access to running terminal commands, then you will be unable to do so.

Although on a separate matter, you could make a compiler, but running it will be extremely difficult, not to mention that Chrome hasn't had Java support in browser for quite some time, and Mozilla is removing it soon from Firefox(if not already on newer versions).

So to summaries; Unless GAE allows you to execute commands, then you will be unable to do so.